# Drawing a 3x3 table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, logicpuzzle

How can I draw a 3x3 table in LaTeX that is numbered? For instance, like those number puzzles where you have to unscramble the board to get the correct order from 1-9 on a 3x3 board.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. At the moment, your question is extremely broad, and it smacks a bit of a do-this-for-me request -- which is, frankly, *not encouraged* on this site). It would be helpful if you provided some more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve. It would also be helpful if you edited your posting to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: maybe you can start trying [here](https://truben.no/table/old/).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `logicpuzzle.sty`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\begin{document}
\begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=3,columns=3,color=yellow!30]
\valueH{1,2,3}
\valueV{1,2,3}
\setrow{3}{4,7,1}
\setrow{2}{2,{},9}
\setrow{1}{3,8,5}
\fillcell{2}{2}
\framepuzzle[black!50]
\end{logicpuzzle}
\end{document}
```

[image: logic puzzle]

Comment: Is graphicx package necessary?

Comment: No, a relict of copy and paste! ;-) Sorry!